# using find_last_of to search a file name

Tags: c++, string

I have a list of file names, as strings, in c++. I store these in a vector.

```
vector<string> files;
```

Using `.find_last_of`, I get the extension.

```
for (int j = 0; j < files.size(); j++)
    {
        if (files[j].substr(files[j].find_last_of(".") + 1) == "tif") {
            images.push_back(files[j]);

        }
```

This all works fine. Now, i need to check the last part of the file name, before the extension.eg, in the file:

```
FileName.1001.tif
```

I am looking to get the `'1001'`

I have tried:

```
if (files[i].substr(files[i].find_last_of(".") - 1) == "1001")
            {
                std::cout << "yaaay..." << std::endl;
            }
```

But it never gets hit. Can I not use a ' - 1' here? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `files[i].substr(files[i].find_last_of(".") - 1)` is `"1.tif"`.

Comment: Ah I see! I was treating it as a split. so using '-4' will give me '1001.tif', and I can just remove the .tif from the string. Thank you!

Comment: you should use sscanf to extract digits as the length of numeric part may be unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking with your current approach you just need to remove the extension and then apply the same "find the last ." logic:

```
std::string getLastPart(const std::string &filename)
{
    // Strip of the extension
    auto name = filename.substr(0, filename.find_last_of('.'));

    // Now get everything to the right of the last .
    auto part = name.substr(name.find_last_of('.') + 1);

    return part;
}
```

NOTE: You need to add some error handling in case the `.` isn't there...

Now you can say:

```
if(getLastPart(files[i]) == "1001")
{
  std::cout << "yaaay..." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The first `std::string::substr` can be eliminated by doing the second `std::string::find_last_of` with starting position of the previously found `.` minus one.

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
if(files[i].substr (str.find("."),str.find_last_of(".")-str.find("."))== "1001")
```

[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/am69JQ)